# Unable to understand this code involving BehaviorSubject and Observables

Tags: rxjs

I am reading this piece of code 
https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-observable-data-services

esp this line

```
this._todos.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).todos);
```

What i don't understand is why after the call to 
Object.assign({}, this.dataStore ) which copies the contents of the datastore to an new object why not do just

```
this._todos.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore))
instead of
this._todos.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).todos)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because it is good practice to expose only the data that a component requires to that component.**

The following line causes the `_todos` Subject to only emit the Todos data:

```
this._todos.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).todos)
```

The code below, which you suggest, would cause the `_todos` subject to emit the entire `dataStore`:

```
this._todos.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore))
```